# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'Log::EMERGENCY' when moving Kohana application to production server

Tags: kohana, kohana-3

This is the first time I have received this error, I have used a local server **and** my own personal hosting provider, this error only pops up on our production server.

error:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'Log::EMERGENCY' in {Kohana Directory}\system\classes\Kohana\Kohana\Exception.php on line 140
```

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Whats your framework version? `Log::EMERGENCY` was added since `3.1`. May be your dev version differs from production

Comment: I have the latest version of Kohana, 3.3

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's a PHP version issue. See here: http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/4631

Use the install.php file to run some checks on your prod server.

Comment: Welp. there's my problem, was told by my sysadmin that he upgraded that server to PHP5.3, it's still 5.2.. didn't think it would be that issue since the sysadmin said he upgraded to 5.3 >>, gonna try and remedy this issue now.